# _wmemcpy replacement for 64 bit programs

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.3.1 from Embarcadero Technology for Windows 10 desktop development. I am converting my code to 64 bit. I have code that uses _wmemcpy. The link below is the Embarcadero dockwiki page for _wmemcpy. At the bottom under "Portability" is indicates _wmemcpy is for Win32 only. I can't find any recommended replacement for 64 bit programs.

[Embarcadero docwiki for _wmemcpy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Memcpy,_wmemcpy)

Below is the code from my C++ file and .h header file where _wmemcpy is used in a while loop. Can you recommend a 64 bit replacement for _wmemcpy.

//FILE: AjIniSec.cpp

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include "AjIniSec.h"
#include "AjIniVal.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <memory.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TAjIniSection::~TAjIniSection()
{

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

wchar_t* __fastcall TAjIniSection::WriteToStr(wchar_t* Str)
{
   IniValIter Iter = FItems.begin();
   IniValIter End = FItems.end();

   while(Iter != End)
   {
      int Len = (*Iter).first.Length();
      _wmemcpy(Str, (*Iter).first.c_str(), Len);
      Str += Len;
      *Str = L'='; ++Str;
      Str = (*Iter).second.WriteToStr(Str);
      ++Iter;
   }

   return Str;
}
```

//FILE: AjIniSec.h

```
#ifndef AjIniSecH
#define AjIniSecH

#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <map>

#include "AjIniVal.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TAjIniVal;
typedef std::map<String, TAjIniVal> TAjIniValMap;
typedef TAjIniValMap::iterator IniValIter;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TAjIniSection
{
private:
   TAjIniValMap FItems;

protected:
   int __fastcall getSize();

public:
   //--------------------
   __fastcall TAjIniSection(){};
   virtual __fastcall ~TAjIniSection();
   //--------------------

   bool __fastcall ReadBool(const String Ident, bool Default);
   int __fastcall ReadInteger(const String Ident, int Default);
   double __fastcall ReadFloat(const String Ident, double Default);
   String __fastcall ReadString(const String Ident, String Default);

   void __fastcall WriteString(const String Ident, String Value);

   wchar_t* __fastcall ReadFromStr(wchar_t* Str);
   wchar_t* __fastcall WriteToStr(wchar_t* Str);

   __property int Size = {read=getSize};
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: It just says `Win32` in the docs.  `Win32` is the MS-Windows API and is either 64-bit or 32-bit depending on your compilation options.  It's a little confusing I know but they called the Win-API Win32 before they had 64-bit systems and the name stuck.  Note the document nesting here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/programming-guide-for-64-bit-windows

Comment: I don't know about Embarcadero but Win32 typically just means Windows (both 32 and 64-bit). Win32 API is the API for non-16-bit Windows and system32 is the system folder on non-16-bit Windows. Even in the link you gave there's no separate column for win64 so if Windows is supported then it should be available on 64-bit Windows

Comment: Once I realized Win32 also means Win64 I tried removing the underscore changing _wmemcpy to wmemcpy. That seems to have worked. I am not sure why but it seems to work when compiled on 64bit. Thanks for helping work that out.

Comment: @homebase Identifiers with leading underscores are vendor-specific extensions.  Hence `_wmemcpy` is not standard.  You might consider replacing it with a standard solution, such as `std::copy(_n)()` in the `<algorithm>` header. Or, since you are dealing with the Embarcadero-specific `System::UnicodeString` class (what `String` maps to in 10.3.1), consider using their `Str(L)Copy()` function in the `<System.SysUtils.hpp>` header